# Ansible nested variable

Tags: filter, ansible, jinja2

I have a variable like this:

`unicast_ip_group: "{{ groups['elasticsearch-demo'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_host']) | join(':9300,') }}:9300"`

I want to make the static value `elasticsearch-demo` a variable. I have tried this but this looks like is not supported in Ansible:

`unicast_ip_group: "{{ groups['{{ my_variable }}'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_host']) | join(':9300,') }}:9300"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
unicast_ip_group: "{{ groups[my_variable] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_host']) | join(':9300,') }}:9300"
```

You already opened a Jinja2 expression with `{{`, so you can use variables just by referring their names.